# Can Windows 8 apps be developed with Visual Studio Online?

Tags: windows-8, cloud, phonegap-build, azure-devops

PhoneGap Build affords the opportunity to build for various platforms "in the cloud"

Is something similar available with Visual Studio Online - can one develop Windows 8 apps, even when their local/client machine is Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Online is basically a source control repository, so no. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-online/info.

The key point would be build. You can build your app on Visual Studio Online (in the same way that TFS can do nightly builds), but you still need the Windows 8 SDK to develop the app, which means you need Windows 8.

Comment: From that tag: *Automated Builds (Cloud Hosted Builds or Bring Your Own Build Farm)*. The [product page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs.aspx) also implies cloud builds, though the information I've seen online is confused on that point.

Comment: The key point would be *build*.  You can build your app on Visual Studio online (in the same way that TFS can do nightly builds), but you still need the Windows 8 SDK to *develop* the app, which means you need Windows 8.

Comment: That'd be a better answer - care to drop it in?

Comment: Edited answer to add this.